# Getting HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request in python

Tags: python, urllib

```
> search_urls=[]
> main_url="https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.html?aid=304142;label=gen173rf-1FCAso7AFCC3Nob3JlLWNsaWZmSDNYA2i0AogBAZgBMbgBF8gBDNgBAegBAfgBAogCAaICDmxvY2FsaG9zdDo4ODg4qAIDuALG9uCRBsACAdICJDc3NjA5M2QzLWI5ZWItNGVjNC05MjRiLTkwMzY5NjdmOTk1MNgCBeACAQ;sid=bacf1e3c790a495b7a5120a3678d30bc;cc1=us;dist=1;pagename=shore-cliff;type=total&;"
> rows=10
> 
> #each page following this:
> #https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.html?label={}&sid={}&cc1={}&pagename{}&srpvid={}&type=total&offset=0&rows=10
> for page in range(0,1):
>     
> 
>     headers = random.choice(headers_list)
>     r = requests.Session()
>     r.headers = headers
>     offset= page*10
>     html = str(main_url)+"&offset="+str(offset)+"&rows="+str(rows)
>     search_urls.append(html)
> 
> for item in search_urls:
>     
> 
>     html = urllib.request.urlopen(item).read().decode('utf-8') #loading each search page
>     print (html)
```

When I try to print out the html content, I am getting error like this:

```
Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    639 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    640     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 641         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    642 
    643 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I have added the header but still doesn't work， does anybody know how I could resolve this problem?
All I want is to read the content of each of the booking hotel review page.

Comment: could you manually navigate to the URL to see if it works? Also, you could try to change the main URL to `https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.html?aid=304142;label=gen173rf-1FCAso7AFCC3Nob3JlLWNsaWZmSDNYA2i0AogBAZgBMbgBF8gBDNgBAegBAfgBAogCAaICDmxvY2FsaG9zdDo4ODg4qAIDuALG9uCRBsACAdICJDc3NjA5M2QzLWI5ZWItNGVjNC05MjRiLTkwMzY5NjdmOTk1MNgCBeACAQ;sid=bacf1e3c790a495b7a5120a3678d30bc;cc1=us;dist=1;pagename=shore-cliff;type=total`

Comment: yes, i can manually navigate to the URL.